# Mouse-click or other short cut to select formatting you want to find and replace? (Word 2010)

Tags: microsoft-word, mouse, microsoft-word-2010

I want to replace one style with another.

Both styles are available to me.

Before: **1.1 This Text is Styled as H2 with Numbers**

After: **This Text is Styled as H2 without Numbers**

Instead of opening the find/replace dialog, I would like to use my mouse to

- select the paragraph mark (where the style is stored), and
- open the find/replace dialog and see that the Find box is already prepopulated with the style

Assuming my logic is feasible (capture the paragraph mark to change the style), then is it possible to do it quickly with a mouse click or two, or in some other manner (vs. clicking through the find/replace menu)?

Comment: I tried clicking inside text (no text selection) + right-clicking.  //  

I also tried selecting the paragraph mark + right-clicking.   //  

Either technique gives me quick access to the styles box and, if I want it, the styles pane.  //  

In styles pane (as far as I can tell) all I can do is a mass (all or none) change for the style I want to replace.

I want the find/replace dialog so I step through each occurrence (do not want to do a mass change).  

I have a lot of intermittent style swapping to do (work interrupts). So anything I can do to reduce the number of steps is all to the good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click the text you want to change the context menu that comes up will have a Styles submenu. On that is an option to select all text in the document with similar formatting. Then you can apply the new style to the selection. I'm not sure how this works if there's direct formatting or character styles involved, though; I rarely use this method.

What I usually do instead is go to the Styles dialog box (the arrow at the bottom right of the Styles group on the Home tab, or Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S). Hovering over a style there will display an arrow for a drop down menu, which allows selecting all occurrences of the style. Then, again, apply the new style to the selection. Since this method allows explicitly specifying the style to select, it won't be messed up by direct formatting or character styles. It gives more control, albeit at the cost of a little simplicity.